# Caminho da URL WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Tenho um serviço Rest em WebApi, gerei os controllers pelo assistente que definiu as repostas em "api/{controller}/{id}", como o exemplo do get por id:

```
 // GET: api/pessoas/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(pessoa))]
        public IHttpActionResult Getpessoa(int id)
        {
            pessoa pessoa = db.pessoa.Find(id);
            if (pessoa == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(pessoa);
        }
```

até ai tudo bem, porém agora preciso consultar pelo cnpj de pessoas tentei fazer assim só que ele não entende:

```
//consultando pessoas pelo cnpj
        // GET: api/pessoas/888888888888
        [ResponseType(typeof(pessoa))]
        public IHttpActionResult Getpessoa_cnpj_cpf(int cnpj_cpf)
        {
            pessoa pessoa = db.pessoa.Find(cnpj_cpf);
            if (pessoa == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(pessoa);
        }
```

Como faço para fica api/cnpj/8888888888 ou qualquer outro caminho contanto que funcine?

Comment: A informação do CPF/CNPJ está sendo registrada no seu banco como int?

Comment: Você adicionou uma rota específica para esse método? Algo como `[Route("{api/pessoas/cnpj/{cnpj_cpf}")]`? Um detalhe: o cnpj tem 14 dígitos, vai dar overflow com o tipo `int`.

Comment: @AnaCarolinaManzan , errei coloquei como int mas no banco está string, alterei pra Getpessoa_cnpj_cpf(string cnpj_cpf)

Comment: @RicardoPontual , defini uma segunda rota da seguinte maneira: `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{cpf_cnpj}",
                defaults: new { cpf_cnpj = RouteParameter.Optional }`

Comment: @InteliderSistemas exato. Como o Ricardo disse, como o CNPJ tem 14 dígitos, se mantiver isso como int vai dar um overflow. Deu certo alterando pra string?

Comment: @AnaCarolinaManzan , alterando para string deu outro erro `"ExceptionMessage": "The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for details.\r\nNome do parâmetro: keyValues",`

Comment: Você ta usando Entity Framework, né? Esse erro está acontecendo pelo seguinte... Quando você usa o `.Find` com o Entity, ele tenta buscar os dados pela chave primária da sua tabela, que neste caso acredito que seja um int. Você vai ter que passar outra instrução pra poder buscar pelo CPF/CNPJ. Um minuto e eu já te passo como fazer.

Comment: @AnaCarolinaManzan , sim estou usando entity framework com codefirst .obrigado fico muito agradecido.

Comment: São várias coisas... primeiro, você pode adicionar a rota na própria `controller`, não precisa ir na configuração.. segundo, se sua tabela tem um campo `int` para o cnpj, vai dar *overflow* ou vai truncar os números. Por último, sua rota pode até aceitar o parâmetro como `string`, mas você precisa converter na hora de obter os dados usando o `Entity Framework`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa realizar as seguintes mudanças:

-> Altere o tipo do parâmetro do método para string

-> Adicione o Annotation `ActionName` à sua Action, assim poderá fazer a chamada do método através de `localhost/pessoas/GetCNPJCPF/{valor_do_parametro}`

-> Em vez de usar `.Find`, use o `.Where`, e faça a comparação dos dados que vem do seu request com a coluna presente na sua tabela do banco.

```
//consultando pessoas pelo cnpj
// GET: api/pessoas/888888888888
[ResponseType(typeof(pessoa))]
[ActionName("GetCNPJCPF")]
public IHttpActionResult Getpessoa_cnpj_cpf(string cnpj_cpf)
{
    pessoa pessoa = db.pessoa.Where(p => p.cnpj_cpf == cnpj_cpf).FirstOrDefault();
    if (pessoa == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(pessoa);
}
```

Para a comparação que fiz no `.Where`: se o campo do CPF/CNPJ não tiver o mesmo nome que eu inclui aqui (no caso p.cnpj_cpf), apenas substitua pelo nome do atributo da sua classe.

Comment: aparentemente funcionou, mas retornou a mensagem: ` "Não foram encontrados recursos HTTP que correspondam ao URI de solicitação 'http://localhost/api/pessoas/GetCNPJCPF/10999558000186'."`, acho que deve ser algum problema na minha rota, defini a mesma no WebApiConfig.

Comment: `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{cnpj_cpf}",
                defaults: new { cpf_cnpj = RouteParameter.Optional });`

Comment: Se você deseja chamar a action dessa forma, você pode resolver adicionando um annotation acima da action assim: `[ActionName("GetCNPJCPF")]`. O que acontece é que o padrão do WebAPI é chamar `api/controller/action/{parametros}`. Para fazer a chamada neste caso, creio que o annotation do action name já resolva.

Comment: Ah! Mantenha essa rota que você criou, ok?

Comment: funcionou. Thanks, salvou minha manha!